# Nagios/Check_MK: How to see effective object definition

Tags: nagios, check-mk

In Nagios (or check_mk), is there a way to see what the final effective object (e.g. host) definition is after all templates, inheritance, etc.?

I want to use this as a test/debug tool to make sure my definitions end up as intended, and also to compare configurations to each other.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There should be a 'status.dat' file in your Nagios installation (usually [Nagios_install]/var/status.dat) that contains a 'flattened' list of all defined checks.

Your main nagios.cfg file should have its location under:

```
Format:     status_file=<file_name>
Example:    status_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/status.dat
```

And also this file:

```
Format:     object_cache_file=<file_name>
Example:    object_cache_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/objects.cache
```

Hope this helps.